# Not able to show help for flags of a command in PowerShell

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, alias

I'm a verbose person so I usually create a new directory without using aliases like this.

> New-Item Donkey -ItemType d

A less verbose colleague nagged about it and, since I'm such a pleasure and joy to work with, I thought I'll short it down, because I want the unverbose people to be content too. So I went like this.

> ni Donkey -ItemType d

Then, something hit me and I tried the following, just for the fun of it, fully expecting to get the slap telling me to go and do stuff to myself.

> ni Donkey -it d

Wouldn't you know? It actually worked! So, happy about making everything totally cryptic for my verbality aversed friend, I started to investigate what else I could abbreviate. I went like this.

> Get-Help ni
>   Get-Help it

Whereas the first one gave me the command including it's alias, just as expected, the second one barked at me telling me there's no such thing. Well, I beg its pardon but I just executed the command so I know there is.

After a few "*There's too! There's not. There's too! There's not.*" I realized that I'm not going to win against the stubborn, red message of PowerShell. So, here's my questions.

1. Is *it* an alias to begin with?
2. How can I get help on *it* (be that alias or something else)?

Comment: 1. "it" is the first 2 letters of -ItemType parameter name. Thus if there is only one parameter that starts with such symbols you may not type the whole name.
2. Get-Help New-Item -Full

Comment: @t1meless is correct (and should post this as an answer). "it" is not an alias, it is a short way to write the parameter and only works because no other parameter for this cmdlet shares the same prefix. You can shorten this parameter to "i", since it is the only parameter for the cmdlet to start with this letter. `Get-Help it` does not yield a result because `Get-Help` returns information for cmdlets, not parameters. More here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262802/shorter-versions-of-powershell-cmdlet-parameters

Comment: @t1meless Hehe, I see it now. I got fooled by the capitalization of *ItemType* and missed that *it* is both that and the prefix. Great info. Also, the flag *-full* will be useful. You should definitely post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerShell we have two types of **Aliases**, for cmdLets/functions and for parameters.

`Get-Alias` shows the defined aliases for CmdLets/Functions

To see the aliases for parameters for `New-Item` you can use:

```
(gcm -Name New-Item).parameters.values | ? { $_.aliases } | ft name, aliases
```

You get:

```
Name         Aliases
----         -------
ItemType     {Type}
Value        {Target}
Verbose      {vb}
Debug        {db}
ErrorAction  {ea}
...
```

So you could use:

```
New-Item Donkey -Type d
```

because `Type` is an alias for `ItemType`

the fact that `-it` works has already been explained in the comments, for parameters you can specify the unique first few letters of the parameter name.

the shortest way to create a directory is:

```
md Donkey
```

`md` is an alias for `mkdir` which in turn is a function that uses `New-Item -ItemType Directory`

If you need to see parameter aliases without remembering the long command above, put the following into your PowerShell profile:

```
function Get-ParameterAlias([string]$cmd)
{
    (gcm -Name $cmd).parameters.values | ? { $_.aliases } | ft name, aliases
}
Set-Alias -Name gpa -Value Get-ParameterAlias
```

Now you can just use: `gpa New-Item` to get its parameter aliases

Comment: I see the command but it's way to complex to be useful in my case. I use PowerShell intensively but only occasionally, so I need something that's very intuitive, regrettably. Nevertheless, +1 for a great answer.

Comment: @KonradViltersten not too complex for your case at all. Just store the function in your PowerShell Profile http://www.howtogeek.com/50236/customizing-your-powershell-profile/ and then just use the function like this in your PowerShell Console `Get-ParameterAlias -cmd New-Item`

Comment: @SimonS That's far above my current PowerShell-fu. I look forward to get it under control though. Thanks for the link. It **will** come in handy. :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten fyi: there's one small error in the link i provided. don't use `test-path $profile` to locate your profile because on my computer it returns `false` even tough i have a profile. just use `$profile` without the `test-path` to locate the profile.

Comment: @SimonS Haven't had time to take a loot at it yet because my system dies after the latest Win 10 upgrade (I'm crying about it [here](http://superuser.com/questions/1138294/cant-boot-up-lenovo-thinkpad-t450-after-latest-windows-10-update), hehe). But I do appreciate your agility.