# Can't boot up Lenovo Thinkpad T450 after latest Windows 10 update

Tags: windows-10, boot, thinkpad

Not sure what to do. The computer comes to live and shows the logotype "Lenovo". Then, nothing, black screen. The fan goes like crazy but nothing happens. Can't enter any recovery menus.

I've made all the possible checks on the hardware through BIOS and all are green. Can't start it up in safe mode for some reason (maybe because it's Win 10).

Totally lost and need suggestions.

Comment: Suggested reading: [Windows 10 security is broken after rollback](https://superuser.com/q/1137968/53590)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot to a WinPE environment using a repair DVD or USB stick and run *bootrec /fixboot* as well as *sfc /scannow* on the C: drive.

Alternatively, boot to a Linux liveCD called "[Boot-Repair-Disk](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/)" and let it do its thing.

Alternatively, take the hard drive out of the laptop and attempt to boot from it in another computer which is compatible with Windows 10.

Isolate the problem to the drive, or something else in the laptop. If it's the drive, you have to either fix it using one of the above methods (Acronis and software like it might also be able to help), or wipe and reinstall, or, if SMART data indicates the drive might be bad, replace the drive (and reinstall windows onto that new drive). If it's not the drive, then the problem is unlikely to be due to your recent Windows 10 install and we would need more information to properly assist, so my answer ends here.

Comment: Thank for the hints. The problem **is** due to Win 10 latest update. It somehow triggers on certain languages and a Lenovo machine with something stuck in the USB port. At the airport I saw a guy crying for the very same reason. In Holland - nothing. But in Denmark, again, same issue. Weird indeed. I reinstalled the Windows. Lost everything. Not happy, hehe.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're saying the problem occurs if and ONLY if you have a Lenovo machine, with one or more USB devices installed, and in certain languages, for a a certain Windows 10 update? 

I wish you had checked the event logs before reinstalling... http://superuser.com/questions/76340/is-it-possible-to-access-the-windows-event-log-if-the-system-is-unbootable

Comment: Short: yes. Longer: there **might** be other affected configurations and the one described by is only one of them. What I meant was that it's not a general threat to **all** Windows and that it's not a specific issue with **my** machine neither. Not sure how I'd be accessing the logs, though. I'm not very good with Linux and I'm not at liberty to open my computer (company/warranty restriction). Anyway, the only thing I have is a screenshot of the error pixelly-thingy at the blue screen of death.

Comment: I linked how you can do it in my comment.